# Outlook VBA - updating Appointment duration

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote/hacked some VBA code that prompted the user to adjust the appointment that they were about to send and reduce the duration a little to allow for a buffer between meetings. It worked fine until some time this year... now it is not adjusting the item being sent, only the one in my calendar.

1. A event handler in `ThisOutlookSession`

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = Not (Module1.AUTOchangeMeetingDuration(Item))
End Sub
```

2. Adjustment function in the module `Module1` to

   - get the `Item`
   - check it is a `olMeetingRequest` being sent
   - get the corresponding `AppointmentItem` for the meeting
   - adjust `Duration`

```vb
Public Function AUTOchangeMeetingDuration(ByVal Item As Object) As Boolean
  AUTOchangeMeetingDuration = True
  If Item.Class <> olMeetingRequest Then Exit Function ' exit if not sending a meeting request
  Dim i As AppointmentItem
  Set i = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)
  If i.Organizer <> "" And i.Organizer <> Application.Session.CurrentUser Then GoTo cleanup 'user is not organiser
  If i.Duration Mod 30 <> 0 Then GoTo cleanup 'duration is not round 30
  Dim x As VbMsgBoxResult
  x = MsgBox("Do you wish to adjust meeting length in accordance with meeting guidelines?" & Chr(10) & _
             "Duration will be adjusted to " & (i.Duration - 5) & "mins (from " & i.Duration & "mins)" _
            , vbYesNoCancel, "Adjust duration before Send?")
  If x = vbYes Then
    i.Duration = i.Duration - 5
  ElseIf x = vbCancel Then
    AUTOchangeMeetingDuration = False
  End If
cleanup:
  Set i = Nothing
  Exit Function
End Function
```

As mentioned previously, this code used to work fine but not any more. There have been updates to our Outlook - e.g. upgrade to 2016 client and to off-premise Outlook365, but I don't recall timelines. By guess is some slight change in the `GetAssociatedAppointment` handling - but I haven't found anything in my search...

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? I.e. run it under the debugger attached and go through each line of code?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - I hadn't, but have now... at the end of the event handler part (1 above) `Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False).Duration` and `Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Duration` both gave the shorter duration... but the invite was still sent with the longer :-(

Comment: In similar situations the solution was to save.

Comment: @niton - thanks for the suggestion. I tried a save in both the `i.Save` and `Item.Save` to no avail :-(

Answer (score 0):

The meeting request went unchanged. The conclusion then is to cancel the original and send a new request.

The `.Send` does not trigger `Application_ItemSend`.

In ThisOutlookSession

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = Module1.AUTOchangeMeetingDuration(Item)
    Debug.Print "Original meeting request cancelled? " & Cancel

End Sub
```

In a regular module, Module1 following the convention in the question.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function AUTOchangeMeetingDuration(ByVal Item As Object) As Boolean

    Dim i As AppointmentItem
    Dim x As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Item.Class <> olMeetingRequest Then
        ' exit if not sending a meeting request
         Exit Function
    End If

    Set i = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)

    If i.Organizer <> "" And i.Organizer <> Application.Session.CurrentUser Then
        'user is not organiser
        Exit Function
    End If

    If i.Duration Mod 30 <> 0 Then
        'duration is not round 30
        Exit Function
    End If

    x = MsgBox("Do you wish to adjust meeting length in accordance with meeting guidelines?" & Chr(10) & _
      "Duration will be adjusted to " & (i.Duration - 5) & "mins (from " & i.Duration & "mins)", _
      vbYesNoCancel, "Adjust duration before Send?")

    If x = vbYes Then
        i.Duration = i.Duration - 5
        'Cancel the original request which is "Item"
        AUTOchangeMeetingDuration = True

        ' Send updated request which is "i"
        ' Does not call Application_ItemSend a second time
        i.Send

    ElseIf x = vbCancel Then
        AUTOchangeMeetingDuration = True
    End If

End Function
```